# Generation field for crd doesn't work in v1.9.2 k8s

Tags: kubernetes

I'm using k8s v1.9.2 and trying to develop a customResourceController. And I found that the crd's Generation field, which is defined in `CRD.ObjectMeta.Generation`, consistently be 0 regardless of the changes of `CRD.Spec.SOMEFIELD`.

Is this a normal behavior or sth is wrongly configured?

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0):

I asked [this question in Github, and get the answer](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/62595).

**nikhita** told me the following:

> For 1.9.2, the metadata.generation for the custom resource will not change as the spec changes. It can be made to increment only from 1.10.